# Debugging a memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

Valgrind reports a memory leak:

```
[18370]
==18367== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==18367==    at 0x4C2EDA1: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18367==    by 0x40334C: runCmd (main.c:444)
==18367==    by 0x40334C: command (main.c:661)
==18367==    by 0x40198E: main (main.c:755)
==18367== 
==18367== 
==18367== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18367==     in use at exit: 82,829 bytes in 175 blocks
==18367==   total heap usage: 274 allocs, 99 frees, 99,482 bytes allocated
==18367== 
==18367== 512 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 70 of 93

********************* TEST WILDCARDS 
***** Press any key to listing all files in current directory...
==18367==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18367==    by 0x402A71: runCmd (main.c:307)
==18367==    by 0x402A71: command (main.c:661)
==18367==    by 0x40198E: main (main.c:755)
==18367== 
==18367== 2,585 (512 direct, 2,073 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 80 of 93
==18367==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18367==    by 0x402A5D: runCmd (main.c:305)
==18367==    by 0x402A5D: command (main.c:661)
==18367==    by 0x40198E: main (main.c:755)
==18367== 
==18367== LEAK SUMMARY:
==18367==    definitely lost: 1,024 bytes in 2 blocks
==18367==    indirectly lost: 2,073 bytes in 6 blocks
==18367==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18367==    still reachable: 79,732 bytes in 167 blocks
==18367==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18367== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==18367== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==18367==
```

This is the offending code:

`main.c:444` ("`free(*matrix);`")

```
 int row;
    if (*matrix != NULL) {
        for (row = 0; row < BUFFER_SIZE; row++) {
                free((*matrix)[row]);
        }
        free(*matrix);
        *matrix = NULL;
    }
```

`main.c:307`

```
 matrix[0] = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(**matrix));
```

`main.c:305`

`char ***matrix = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(char *));`

The whole function `runCmd` is

```
static int runCmd(const char *cmd) {
    char *pString1[z];
    char *pString[z];
    *pString1 = "\0";
    *pString = "\0";
    bool quote = false;
    char **ptr;
    struct command shellcommand[64];
    char **ptr1;
    char **argv;
    int argc = 1;
    int n = 0;
    int status = 0;

    char *pString4[z][z];
    char **pString5[z];
    int i4 = 0;
    for (int f = 0; f < z; f++) {
        pString5[f] = NULL; /* initialize */
        for (i4 = 0; i4 < z; i4++) {
            pString4[f][i4] = NULL;
        }
    }
    char ***matrix = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(char *));
  //  *matrix = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(**matrix));
    matrix[0] = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(**matrix));
    //  if (cmd) {
    char *cmdtmp;
    char *pString3[64];
    cmdtmp = strdup(cmd);
    ptr1 = str_split(pString3, cmdtmp, '|');
    int w = 0;
    int i2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; ptr1[i]; i++) { /* loop for each pipeline */
        n++;                 /* save number of pipelines */
        pString5[n] = NULL;
        char *string1[z];
        int e = 0;
        *pString = "\0";
        *string1 = strdup(ptr1[i]);
        if ((*string1[0] != '\0') &&
            !isspace(*string1[0])) {
            /*   parse_command(w, ptr, string1, pString, pString5, i2, n, quote, i, string, pString1,
                              e, &argc,  &argv, pInt, pString4);
               printf("string %s", * string[i]);*/
            char *pString2[64];
            ptr = str_split(pString2, *string1, ' ');
            pString5[i2] = ptr;
            i2++;
            char *temp = {'\0'};
            int y = 0;
            int p = 0;
            for (int j = 0; ptr[j]; j++) {
                if (ptr + j && !quote && strstr(ptr[j], "'")) {
                    quote = true;
                    strcpy(temp, ptr[j]);
                    if (y < 1) {
                        y++;
                    }
                }
                while_quote(&quote, y, i, ptr, j, temp, *matrix);
                bool keep = false;
                if (ptr + j) { ;
                    if (*(ptr + j)[0] == '{') {
                        keep = true;
                    }
                    if (testFn(*(ptr + j))) {
                        matrix[i][j - p] = concat(*pString1, ptr[j]);
                        keep = false;
                        free(*pString1);
                        continue;
                    }
                    char *str;
                    if (keep) {
                        str = concat(*pString1, ptr[j]);
                        *pString1 = concat(str, " ");
                        free(str);
                        p++;
                    } else {
                        bool b1 = false;
                        int i3 = j;
                        pString4[i][0] = *pString;
                        //   printf("i: %d", i);
                        str = "\0";
                        b1 = parse(b1, i, &j, &e, ptr, i3, pString, str, pString4[i]);
                        if (make_args(pString4[i][e - 1], &argc, (const char ***) &argv)) {
                            write_command(w, argc, argv, matrix);;
                            w++;
                        }
                        else if (!b1) {
                            for (int r = 0; argv[r] != NULL; r++) {
                                matrix[i][r] = argv[r];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            bool boo = false;
            //  dump_argv((const char *) "d", argc, argv, boo);
        }
        free(*string1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        shellcommand[i].argv = matrix[i];
    }
    fflush(NULL);
    /* refactor to a function */
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork failed");
        return -1;
    }
    /* If we are the child process, then go execute the string.*/
    if (pid == 0) {
        /* spawn(cmd);*/
        fork_pipes(n, shellcommand);
    }
    /*
     * We are the parent process.
     * Wait for the child to complete.
     */

    while (((pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) < 0) && (errno == EINTR));
    if (pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error from waitpid: %s", strerror(errno));
        free(cmdtmp);
        if (ptr1) {
            for (int i = 0; ptr1[i]; i++) {
                free(ptr1[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            free(ptr1);
        }
        return -1;
    }
    if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pid %ld: killed by signal %d\n",
                (long) pid, WTERMSIG(status));
        free(cmdtmp);
        if (ptr1) {
            for (int i = 0; ptr1[i]; i++) {
                free(ptr1[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            free(ptr1);
        }
        return -1;
    }

    free(cmdtmp);
    if (ptr1) {
        for (int i = 0; ptr1[i]; i++) {
            free(ptr1[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        free(ptr1);
    }

    int row;
    if (*matrix != NULL) {
        for (row = 0; row < BUFFER_SIZE; row++) {
                free((*matrix)[row]);
        }
        free(*matrix);
        *matrix = NULL;
    }


    int z;
    for (int f = 0; f < n; f++) {
        for (z = 0; pString4[f][z]; z++) {
            free(pString4[f][z]);
        }
        // free( pString4[f]);
    }
    //free(* pString4);
    //** pString4 = NULL;

    size_t idx;
    for (int f = 0; n > 1 && f < n; f++) {
        for (idx = 0; *(pString5[f] + idx) != NULL; idx++) {
            free(*(pString5[f] + idx));
        }
        free(pString5[f]);
    }
//    free(** pString5);
    *pString5 = NULL;
    free(*matrix );
    return WEXITSTATUS(status);
}
```

There is also a detailed report about the same lines:

```
==19171== 512 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 77 of 101
==19171==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19171==    by 0x402A5D: runCmd (main.c:305)
==19171==    by 0x402A5D: command (main.c:661)
==19171==    by 0x40194E: main (main.c:760)
==19171== 
==19171== 512 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 78 of 101
==19171==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19171==    by 0x402A71: runCmd (main.c:307)
==19171==    by 0x402A71: command (main.c:661)
==19171==    by 0x40194E: main (main.c:760)
```

Some backend code to execute processes that is probably free of bugs:

```
/* Helper function that forks pipes */
void fork_pipes(int n, struct command *cmd) {
    int i;
    int in = 0;
    int fd[2];

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {

        if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
            err_syserr("Failed creating pipe");
        }

        spawn_proc(in, fd[1], cmd + i);
        close(fd[1]);
        in = fd[0];
    }
    if (dup2(in, 0) < 0) {
        err_syserr("dup2() failed on stdin for %s: ", cmd[i].argv[0]);
    }
    /*fprintf(stderr, "%d: executing %s\n", (int) getpid(), cmd[i].argv[0]);*/
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    execvp(cmd[i].argv[0], cmd[i].argv);
    err_syserr("failed to execute %s: ", cmd[i].argv[0]);
}
```

Link to the repo with all the code https://github.com/montao/openshell

Comment: The valgrind output clearly indicates that the leaked object is allocated in `runCmd`, not in `write_command`. So, you should look at `runCmd` first.

Comment: I posted the entire `runCmd` now. The memory leak is 512 bytes.

Comment: Why are you saving to a triple-pointer the result of `malloc()`? There is way too much code to sift through here. Have you stepped through a debugger?

Comment: @Qix I tried with `gdb` and Clion's debugger but they don't report memory leaks iiuc. I have to use a matrix to build up an internal data structure. I am not an expert in C programming, especially at this detailed level. Maybe you can see where 1024 or 512 bytes are wrong.

Comment: Headline "3 start programmer has memory problems" Why aren't I suprised..

Comment: @John3136 Yes, it's easy to be wrong about the stars in C.

Comment: What does `fork_pipes()` do?  Does it return?

Comment: @Montao Then don't have so many stars. Break your code down into smaller pieces that take parameters so you can use less stars.

Comment: @Montao The point of debugging in a debugger isn't necessarily to find leaks, it's to check the logic of your code. Your leaks are a direct result of incorrect code, and I bet you if you sat down and worked out what your code *actually* did vs. what you want it to be doing, you'd not need to ask here for help ;)

Comment: That's a really horrible function you have there. I say that not to embarrass you but to point out that such a long and rambling function is going to be very difficult for you to understand and debug let along for someone else to do the same. It'll be doing yourself a favour if you try to simplify the code using standard techniques such as breaking the code up into smaller functions.

Comment: @Qix I use Clion which has a debugger but it says "cannot collect variable" too ofter and and don't know what that means. I created an issue for that at JetBrains. A debugger where you can't inspect the variable!

Comment: @Montao debuggers are generally pretty smart. There's usually a good reason why it can't do something - a lot of those problems are chalked up to the fact machine code isn't at all straightforward to debug.

Comment: I look in the debugger at the values of the matrix and they look just right. The output is also correct. I've written a test that reproduces the memory leak so that I can check if I make it better or worse when I adjust variables. But I feel I need to know which variable to change. It's probably something about the matrix and the three stars.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I posted the function `fork_pipes` and a link to the repo with all the code. It's only one memory leak and only 1024 byte. The size of the memory leak is the same as the buffer size so that indicates a mistake of one dimension somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crux of your problematic code goes like this:

```
char ***matrix = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(char *));
matrix[0] = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(**matrix));

pid = fork();

/* If we are the child process, then go execute the string.*/
if (pid == 0) {
    /* spawn(cmd);*/
    fork_pipes(n, shellcommand);
}
/*
 * We are the parent process.
 * Wait for the child to complete.
 */
while (((pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) < 0) && (errno == EINTR));

if (*matrix != NULL) {
    for (int row = 0; row < BUFFER_SIZE; row++) {
            free((*matrix)[row]);
    }
    free(*matrix);
    *matrix = NULL;
}

free(*matrix );
```

So first you create `matrix` which is a pointer to an array of `char**`, which basically looks like a 3D array.  Note that `sizeof(char*)` is a mismatch for `char**`, so that's a bug but not an important one.

Then you initialize the first element of `matrix`, which is now an array of `char*`.  But those pointers are uninitialized.  You later pass `*matrix` (aka `matrix[0]`) to a function you haven't shown us.

So that whole thing is a mess, because the types don't match, the arrays are largely unused, and have sizes which are probably wrong, and we can't see what other bugs exist in `while_quote()`.

But the leak--where does it come from?  Well, you `fork()` and then the child calls `fork_pipes()`.  Either that function never returns, and `matrix` is leaked in the child process, or it does return, and then the rest of the code is wrong because the parent logic continues executing in the child process.

You see, when you `fork()` you end up with two copies of all your memory, including `matrix`, and you need to `free()` them in each process.

Finally, your `free()` loop at the bottom seems like it invokes undefined behavior, because it operates on elements of `matrix` which were never initialized.  And the final `free(*matrix)` is redundant and another red flag; you never attempt to `free(matrix)` which was presumably meant there.

---

Edit: Perhaps you want something like this:

```
/* returns an array of arrays of char*, all of which NULL */
char*** alloc_matrix(unsigned rows, unsigned columns) {
    char*** matrix = malloc(rows * sizeof(char**));
    if (!matrix) abort();

    for (unsigned row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        matrix[row] = malloc(columns * sizeof(char*));
        if (!matrix[row]) abort();
        for (unsigned column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
            matrix[row][column] = NULL;
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

Then:

```
/* deallocates an array of arrays of char*, calling free() on each */
void free_matrix(char*** matrix, unsigned rows, unsigned columns) {
    for (unsigned row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (unsigned column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
            free(matrix[row][column]);
        }
        free(matrix[row]);
    }
    free(matrix);
}
```

Assuming that the elements (strings) inside the matrix are populated with strings created by `malloc()`, `strdup()`, etc., this gives you a matching pair of functions which can be used to reliably allocate and deallocate your matrix.  Be sure to deallocate in every forked process, not just one.

Comment: The memory leak appeared when I did refactoring. First I used a `char` matrix but I want it to be dynamic. Maybe it is just the initialization? Because it worked before and didn't leak to the child process before. Now I only seem to have this one leak for 2000 LOC but I need to find which variable I need to change and where. I'm currently stepping through it in a debugger and the values look right. `while_quote` is not executed to reproduce the memory leak, so we can probably disregard it. My values and my output from the program is correct and it compiiles without warning.

Comment: @Montao: It seems to me that `matrix` is meant to be a 2D array of strings.  If that's true, you need to malloc once to create the array of pointers to rows, then ROWS times to create the rows themselves.  But instead of `1+ROWS` allocations, you do 2 allocations, and you end up with a 2D array where the first row consists of uninitialized pointers, and the other rows are missing.  Then at the end you free a bunch of stuff in ways that totally do not match the way you allocated them, which probably means you have undefined behavior.  I will shortly edit my answer to include some example code.

Comment: I'm going to try and change the allocation then to `1+ROW` allocations.  You are right, I'm trying to use `matrix` to represent a program that has arguments and pipeline (shell command language) where the first row is the first pipeline and the columns are arguments of the pipeline that `fork_pipes` will execute.

Comment: @Montao: I've added functions to my answer which you can use to create and destroy your matrix of strings.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes! Now the leak is only 65 bytes. So it's some other minor leak. We fixed the major issue.